# windows phone 8.1 cordova plugins 4.2.0 open a local file

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins

all

Use windows phone 8.0, this method was well,can launch files.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(localFile);
```

But , in windows phone 8.1 , this method was wrong:
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is the solution i found out:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
{
    var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appdata:///local/"+fileName);
    StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
    if (file != null)
    {
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
});
```